# Horizontal overflow on my profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, meta

On my profile page on Meta Stack Exchange, the lines with the “summary”, etc. tab headings spills “votes” onto a second line.

[image: screenshot]

Observed with Chrome 33.0.1750.149, Chrome 34.0.1847.116, Firefox 27.0.1 and Firefox 28.0 (all on Linux), at 100% zoom level (they all fit at 110% zoom level).

Comment: Too many outstanding notice, clear it. (Btw +1, repro'd )

Comment: No repro for me, maybe after you update Chrome to 34 it will be solved.. ?

Comment: @ShadowWizard No difference, you probably have fewer unread tabs.

Comment: Got it! [This is how my current tabs look like](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6cbDd.png). If I manually change the unread favorites count (using dev tools) to 50, I get exactly what you see.

Comment: Looks like this has been fixed, sort of.  The new styling looks kind of wonky to me (why is it *left*-aligned now?), but it does seem to be narrower.